# Depth-First Search of a Graph

Tags: java, graph, computer-science, traversal, depth-first-search

I am a bit confused with this example . Normally the depth- first search of a graph is done in alphabetical/ increasing order . (Is it possible for vertex M to be visited third? starting from vertex B ) . Can someone please explain this to me :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to visit vertex *M* as third vertex when starting from *B*, namely starting at *B*, then visiting its neighbour *A* and then visiting *A's* neighbour *M*. Note that for depth-first-search, as presented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), there is usually no rule in which order the neighbours of a vertex are visited, such that usually the visiting sequence of the vertices is not uniquely determined.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation :)